# Set the cache directory for com.apple.dt.instruments

Tags: ios, caching, testing, diskspace

There are a number of test machines on our CI farm. I've noticed the Mac machines have started to run out of disk space. This is caused by the directory `/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.instruments`.

Obviously the tests are causing this growth. Is it possible for me to redirect them to create the cache in our Jenkins workspace? i.e. So the cache will be deleted between runs.

Comment: Have you tried symlinking the cache directory?

Comment: @Losiowaty you know that's a very good idea, I'll give it a shot. Since the bounty expires in one day you might want to put that up as an answer (ideally checking that it actually works before, I don't have access to mac right now) so I can grant it to you.

Comment: Didn't come here for the bounty :) Especially since I wasn't able to confirm that it works :/ On the other hand, what stops you from simply `rm -rf`'ing the whole troublesome directory? I do realize this may be an overkill, but still :)

Comment: @Losiowaty it's a build machine (Jenkins) so I want something automatic. I could write a job that cleans it periodically, but symlinking it to `/tmp` that gets cleaned up automatically every 3 days sounds even better. You might as well write it in an answer (even if you don't have time to check), otherwise the bounty will be lost...

Comment: What happens when you've different workspace names? e.g. /local/workspace/Test_1 versus /local/workspace/Test_2.

Comment: @ShaneGannon why should that make a difference? The instruments cache folder appears to be global/shared for all workspaces: `/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.instruments`

Comment: I read the suggestion by @Losiowaty to mean /Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.instruments should be turned into a symlink to the workspace. Which I thought might be a problem if the workspace name changed between jobs. But you could get each job to reset the link.

Comment: @Losiowaty so it turns out the symlink is a bad idea after all.. *we started getting errors like this one: [INST STDERR] 2016-10-27 14:26:41.016 instruments[5025:249722] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Fatal', reason: 'Cannot create temporary directory for Instruments Analysis Core: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The file â€œcom.apple.dt.instrumentsâ€ couldnâ€™t be saved in the folder â€œCachesâ€." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.instruments, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fa8fad8a2c0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=5 "Input/output error"}}'*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there doesn't appear to be any reliable way to do this, I suggest a scheduled script that cleans it up. For example, to clean up old subfolders that haven't been accessed in 30 days:

```
INSTFLD="/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.instruments"
find $INSTFLD -type d -atime +30 -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```